# Standard ML: how to execute another function within a function?

Tags: sml

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
fun gradImage () =
    let val iImg = Gdimage.image(640,480) (0,0,0);
        val void = mapi gradient iImg;
    in
        Gdimage.toPng iImg "gradient.png"
    end;
```

mapi is a function with type int*int->int*int*int->image->unit. Essentially it operates on the image supplied.

The function looks ugly with val void = ...

How could I eliminate that?

Comment: Others beat me to the answer, so I'll just add the note that the semicolons after the `val = ...` are unnecessary.  I also tend to use an underscore for side-effect-only val: `val _ = mapi`, but that's just a style thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a list of expressions between `in` and `end` in a `let` expression. So you could rewrite your code to

```
fun gradImage () =
    let
        val iImg = Gdimage.image(640,480) (0,0,0)
    in
        mapi gradient iImg;
        Gdimage.toPng iImg "gradient.png"
    end;
```

I assume `mapi` modifies `iImg` in place, as the code seems to be written that way. That doesn't sound very functional; it would feel more natural to have `mapi` return the modified `image`, but from what I can see of the Gdimage interface, it looks like how it's done there, and I understand it's probably better from efficiency perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a decade since I've used SML, but I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
fun gradImage () =
    let val iImg = Gdimage.image(640,480) (0,0,0)
    in
        ignore (mapi gradient iImg);
        Gdimage.toPng iImg "gradient.png"
    end;
```

Comment: The call to `ignore` isn't actually necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer the additional type-checking offered by

```
val () = mapi gradient iImg
```

If this looks ugly, it should—it's not very functional, and Standard ML is definitely a functional language.